# R Tidyverse - Counting the number a word appears in a list by group

Tags: r, stringr

I am currently working on the following:

I have two dataframes. One dataframe contains a number of inventors per company and I would like to know how often their name appears in another dataframe in the same company.The company identifier (df_itemnumber_rounded) in both dataframes is called the same and present in both dataframes.

Example:

First dataframe includes:

```
df_itemnumber_rounded <- c(df_2002_77, df_2002_77, df_2002_77, df_2002_78
,df_2002_767)

assignees_split <- c("DSM IP ASSETS BV","DSM NV,GIST BROCADES NV","INRA INST NAT RECH AGRONOMIQUE","DE FORENEDE BRYGGERIER AS", "FORENEDE BRYGGERIER" )
```

Second dataframe includes:

```
df_itemnumber_rounded <- c(df_2002_77,df_2002_77,df_2002_77,df_2002_77,df_2002_77)

citedp_assignee <- c("LANGEJAN AREND","PELLETIER RENE FRANCOIS ROGER ","LESAFFRE &amp; CIE","GIST BROCADES NV ", "DISTILLERS CO YEAST LTD ")
```

The aim is to have the first dataframe that includes a new variable ("counts") that shows how often a name appears within a company.

So like this:

| df_itemnumber_rounded | assignees_split | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| df_2002_77 | DSM IP ASSETS BV | 0 |
| df_2002_77 | GIST BROCADES NV | 1 |

I have tried to work on it using str_detect and sum but I don't kow how to do it by group instead of letting it run over the whole dataframe.

```
counts <- test_distinct_cleaned %>% 
  group_by(df_itemnumber_rounded,assignees_split) %>% 
mutate(counts=map_int(tolower(test_distinct_cleaned$assignees_split),~sum(str_detect(tolower(match_with_cleaned$citedp_assignee),.x))))
```

However, it takes a long time and does not seem to come to an end. I have tried the solution above without the group_by function on a smaller df where it counts all the appearances of a name and not just the one of the same company. So I am not sure whether this works at all with the group_by and if there is a faster way to do it. The first df has 17000 lines and the second to match with has over 150000 lines...

Below there is a real example of the data:

Dataframe 1 are the assignees.

```
    structure(list(df_itemnumber_rounded = c("df_2012_2175", "df_2012_2175", 
"df_2012_2175", "df_2012_2175", "df_2012_2175", "df_2012_2175", 
"df_2012_2175", "df_2002_4897", "df_2002_4897", "df_2012_9460", 
"df_2012_9460", "df_2012_9460", "df_2012_9460", "df_2016_6247", 
"df_2016_6247", "df_2016_6247", "df_2016_6248", "df_2016_6248", 
"df_2016_6248", "df_2016_6248", "df_2016_6248", "df_2016_6248", 
"df_2012_9459", "df_2012_9459", "df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14178", 
"df_2016_14689", "df_2016_14689", "df_2016_15814", "df_2016_15814", 
"df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", 
"df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", "df_2012_8944", 
"df_2012_8944", "df_2012_8944", "df_2012_3604", "df_2012_3604", 
"df_2012_3604", "df_2012_3604", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", 
"df_2012_4967", "df_2012_7883", "df_2012_7883", "df_2012_7883", 
"df_2012_4836", "df_2012_4836", "df_2012_4836", "df_2002_18770", 
"df_2012_1305", "df_2012_2576", "df_2012_10710", "df_2012_5541", 
"df_2012_5578", "df_2012_5635", "df_2012_6044", "df_2012_6219", 
"df_2012_6317", "df_2012_6488", "df_2012_6500", "df_2012_6613", 
"df_2012_6615", "df_2012_6679", "df_2012_6928", "df_2012_6977", 
"df_2012_7489", "df_2012_7552", "df_2012_7667", "df_2012_8017", 
"df_2012_8302", "df_2012_8555", "df_2012_8809", "df_2012_9085", 
"df_2012_9171", "df_2012_9298", "df_2012_9813", "df_2012_10236", 
"df_2012_10437", "df_2012_10532", "df_2012_10602", "df_2012_11037", 
"df_2012_11070", "df_2012_11183", "df_2012_11606", "df_2012_12362", 
"df_2012_12618", "df_2016_678", "df_2016_790", "df_2016_1079", 
"df_2016_1414", "df_2016_1539", "df_2016_2074", "df_2016_2167", 
"df_2016_2314", "df_2016_2769"), `Publication Number` = c("WO2006046567A1", 
"WO2006046567A1", "WO2006046567A1", "WO2006046567A1", "WO2006046567A1", 
"WO2006046567A1", "WO2006046567A1", "DE3149931A1", "DE3149931A1", 
"WO2013002007A1", "WO2013002007A1", "WO2013002007A1", "WO2013002007A1", 
"WO2016114276A1", "WO2016114276A1", "WO2016114276A1", "WO2016114277A1", 
"WO2016114277A1", "WO2016114277A1", "WO2016114277A1", "WO2016114277A1", 
"WO2016114277A1", "JP2013005781A", "JP2013005781A", "WO2017094654A1", 
"WO2017094654A1", "JP2017112924A", "JP2017112924A", "WO2017169107A1", 
"WO2017169107A1", "WO2006070828A1", "WO2006070828A1", "WO2006070828A1", 
"WO2006070828A1", "WO2006070828A1", "WO2006070828A1", "WO2006070828A1", 
"JP2012183063A", "JP2012183063A", "JP2012183063A", "WO2007097088A1", 
"WO2007097088A1", "WO2007097088A1", "WO2007097088A1", "WO2009017116A1", 
"WO2009017116A1", "WO2009017116A1", "WO2011145670A1", "WO2011145670A1", 
"WO2011145670A1", "WO2008153118A1", "WO2008153118A1", "WO2008153118A1", 
"JP2013066497A", "JP2011030577A", "JP2011142922A", "JP2012105673A", 
"JP2009213393A", "JP2009225740A", "JP2009254247A", "AU2008297027A1", 
"JP2010130902A", "JP2010136658A", "JP2010207213A", "JP2010207217A", 
"JP2010220529A", "JP2010220536A", "JP2010252640A", "JP2011036129A", 
"JP2011030517A", "JP2011135841A", "JP2011142890A", "JP2011206047A", 
"JP2012024081A", "JP2012055235A", "JP2012105572A", "JP2012147775A", 
"JP2012213373A", "WO2012147465A1", "JP2012244965A", "JP2013042751A", 
"WO2013073628A1", "JP2013143938A", "JP2013150602A", "JP2013165707A", 
"JP2013255490A", "JP2013243970A", "JP2014000055A", "JP2014057537A", 
"EP2737810A1", "JP2014128251A", "JP2014217315A", "WO2014192826A1", 
"JP2015015926A", "WO2015029605A1", "JP2015053920A", "WO2015064748A1", 
"JP2015116187A", "JP2015100294A", "WO2015098744A1"), assignees_split = structure(c(19L, 
15L, 17L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 18L, 20L, 16L, 21L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 21L, 
12L, 14L, 21L, 12L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 21L, 14L, 21L, 14L, 21L, 
14L, 21L, 14L, 21L, 15L, 17L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 22L, 15L, 16L, 
23L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 23L, 15L, 16L, 23L, 15L, 16L, 24L, 15L, 16L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), .Label = c(" FURUKUBO S ", 
" IBUSUKI D ", " ICHIMURA A ", " IZUMI T ", " KAKUDO Y ", " KIMURA M ", 
" MAKI H ", " MIYAO Y", " NAGAO K ", " NAKAHARA K", " SUNTORY BEVERAGE&FOOD LTD ", 
" SUNTORY FOOD & BEVERAGE CO LTD ", " SUNTORY HOLDINGS CO LTD ", 
" SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD", " SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD ", " SUNTORY LTD", 
" SUNTORY LTD ", " TAKAOKA S", "KOMATSU MFG CO LTD ", "SUN CHEM CORP ", 
"SUNTORY BEVERAGE & FOOD LTD ", "SUNTORY FOOD & BEVERAGE CO LTD ", 
"SUNTORY HOLDING LTD ", "SUNTORY HOLDINGS CO LTD ", "SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Dataframe are the assignees of the cited patents so cited_assignees.

```
structure(list(df_itemnumber_rounded = c("df_2012_2175", "df_2012_2175", 
"df_2012_2175", "df_2012_2175", "df_2012_2175", "df_2012_2175", 
"df_2002_4897", "df_2012_9460", "df_2012_9460", "df_2012_9460", 
"df_2012_9460", "df_2012_9460", "df_2012_9460", "df_2012_9460", 
"df_2016_6247", "df_2016_6247", "df_2016_6247", "df_2016_6247", 
"df_2016_6247", "df_2016_6247", "df_2016_6248", "df_2016_6248", 
"df_2016_6248", "df_2016_6248", "df_2016_6248", "df_2016_6248", 
"df_2012_9459", "df_2012_9459", "df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14178", 
"df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14178", 
"df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14178", 
"df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14178", "df_2016_14689", 
"df_2016_14689", "df_2016_14689", "df_2016_14689", "df_2016_14689", 
"df_2016_14689", "df_2016_15814", "df_2016_15814", "df_2016_15814", 
"df_2016_15814", "df_2016_15814", "df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", 
"df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", 
"df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", 
"df_2012_2360", "df_2012_2360", "df_2012_8944", "df_2012_3604", 
"df_2012_3604", "df_2012_3604", "df_2012_3604", "df_2012_3604", 
"df_2012_3604", "df_2012_3604", "df_2012_3604", "df_2012_3604", 
"df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", 
"df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", 
"df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", 
"df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", 
"df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", "df_2012_4967", 
"df_2012_7883", "df_2012_7883", "df_2012_7883", "df_2012_7883", 
"df_2012_7883", "df_2012_4836"), citedp_assignee = structure(c(40L, 
23L, 48L, 6L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 30L, 1L, 52L, 53L, 58L, 56L, 3L, 
52L, 52L, 16L, 66L, 52L, 67L, 16L, 66L, 52L, 68L, 52L, 51L, 63L, 
3L, 60L, 27L, 45L, 52L, 9L, 73L, 33L, 25L, 52L, 50L, 62L, 73L, 
64L, 2L, 59L, 28L, 28L, 52L, 46L, 4L, 42L, 1L, 42L, 43L, 31L, 
70L, 32L, 57L, 39L, 14L, 35L, 11L, 56L, 32L, 32L, 55L, 17L, 22L, 
22L, 56L, 56L, 5L, 36L, 56L, 41L, 21L, 20L, 29L, 18L, 19L, 47L, 
7L, 63L, 4L, 38L, 44L, 65L, 56L, 44L, 26L, 34L, 65L, 69L, 10L, 
24L, 8L, 71L, 49L, 54L, 61L, 72L, 37L), .Label = c("  ", "ABURADA MASAKI,TOKIWA PHYTOCHEMICAL CO LTD ", 
"ASAHI BREWERIES LTD", "ASAHI BREWERIES LTD ", "ASAHI BREWERIES LTD,JIBIKI MAKIKO ", 
"CERESTAR HOLDING BV ", "CHOYA UMESHU CO LTD ", "CHUKO SHUZO KK", 
"CREAGRI INC,CREA ROBERTO,MATTEUZZI FRANCESCO,ASTORE STEFANO,MILIONI IVANO ", 
"DEZAINAA FOODS KYOKAI KK ", "FUKUI HISASHI ", "GULF OIL CORP", 
"HOKKAIDO WAIN KK", "IKEDA SHOKKEN KK ", "INSUCHI PUROBUREMU NADEJINOSUT ", 
"ITO EN LTD ", "ITOEN KK", "JAPAN MAIZE PROD ", "KANEBO LTD ", 
"KANEBO LTD,HASEGAWA T CO LTD ", "KIRIN BREWERY", "KIRIN BREWERY ", 
"KIRIN BREWERY,JAPAN MAIZE PROD ", "KOHJIN CO ", "LION CORP ", 
"MANNS WINE CO LTD ", "MARUNAKA SHOKUHIN KK ", "MARUZEN PHARMA ", 
"MATSUSHITA ELECTRIC IND CO LTD ", "MATSUTANI KAGAKU KOGYO KK ", 
"MEIJI DAIRIES CORP ", "MEIJI MILK PROD CO LTD ", "MILLER BREWING INTERNATIONAL INC,LUSK LANCE T,RYDER DAVID S ", 
"MITSUBISHI CHEM IND ", "MITSUBISHI HEAVY IND LTD,KADO TAKASHI,ISOZAKI TOSHIKAZU ", 
"MIYAGI PREFECTURE,MIYAGIKEN SHUZO KYODO KUMIAI ", "NAT TAX ADMINISTRATION AGENCY ", 
"NIPPON BEET SUGAR MFG ", "OGAWA &amp; CO LTD ", "OKURA SYUZO KK ", 
"OZEKI KK ", "PEPSICO INC ", "PEPSICO INC,LEE THOMAS,NATTRESS LAURA ANN,RIHA WILLIAM", 
"POLA CHEM IND INC ", "RIVERSON KK ", "SAN EI GEN FFI INC", "SAN EI GEN FFI INC ", 
"SAPPORO BREWERIES ", "SAPPORO BREWERIES,OONO MASAO,SANO TOMOHIRO ", 
"SHOWA PHARM CHEM IND ", "SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD", "SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD ", 
"SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD,IDO YOSHIHIRO,KOMINE TETSUYA ", "SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD,KAGEYAMA NORIHIKO,INUI TAKAKO,TAKAGI DAISUKE ", 
"SUNTORY LTD", "SUNTORY LTD ", "SUNTORY LTD,KAGEYAMA NORIHIKO,NAKAHARA KOICHI,INUI TAKAKO,TAKAOKA SEISUKE,NAGAMI KENZO ", 
"SUNTORY LTD,WATANABE TOKUTOMI,DAIDO HIROMI,YOSHIHIRO AKIRA ", 
"SYMRISE GMBH &amp; CO KG ", "TAISHO PHARMA CO LTD ", "TAKARA HOLDINGS INC ", 
"TAKARA SHOKUHIN KK ", "TAKARA SHUZO CO ", "TAKASAGO PERFUMERY CO LTD", 
"TOKYO SHIBAURA ELECTRIC CO ", "TOYO SEIKAN KAISHA LTD ", "TROPICANA PROD INC", 
"TROPICANA PROD INC ", "TSUKISHIMA KIKAI CO ", "UNILEVER PLC,UNILEVER NV,LEVER HINDUSTAN LTD ", 
"WOONGJIN FOODS CO LTD ", "YAKULT HONSHA KK,KUMAMOTOKEN KAJITSU NOGYO KYOD", 
"YAMADA YASUYUKI "), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi. PLease check your inputs, I assume the company identifier is a character variable and in the first data you have 5 company identifiers, but only 4 assigness_split. This doesn't work. Likewise in the second data frame you have only three values for citedp, but 5 identifiers.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have adapted the example. So the number of identifiers is the same as the number of values. But please note the number of inventors can be different. So one company can have 5 assignees (assignees split) and 7 cited assignees (citedp assignee).

Comment: Do you want to find how often each assignee from data 1 occurs in the citedp from data 2 or do you want to find out how often a citedp value occurs in assigneesplit in data1?

Comment: Also which role does the itemnumber play? It doesn‘t seem to serve any purpose here? At least not for finding the matches.

Comment: I want to find how often each assignee from data 1 appears in the same company in data two. The itemnumber is the company identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a potential solution. Note that your assignee and citetp variables are messy with whitespaces at the beginning/end taht you might not want to take into account for your string search:

library(tidyverse)

```
df1 <- data.frame(df_itemnumber_rounded = c("df_2002_77", "df_2002_77", "df_2002_77", "df_2002_78", "df_2002_767"),
                  assignees_split = c("DSM IP ASSETS BV","DSM NV,GIST BROCADES NV","INRA INST NAT RECH AGRONOMIQUE","DE FORENEDE BRYGGERIER AS", "FORENEDE BRYGGERIER" ))


df2 <- data.frame(citedp_assignee = c("LANGEJAN AREND","PELLETIER RENE FRANCOIS ROGER ","LESAFFRE &amp; CIE","GIST BROCADES NV ", "DISTILLERS CO YEAST LTD "))
```

The solution below gives ou the full information about which assignees appear in the citedp variable:

```
df1 |> 
  mutate(is_match = str_detect(tolower(assignees_split),
                               paste0(tolower(trimws(df2$citedp_assignee, which = "both")),
                                      collapse = "|"))) |>
  group_by(df_itemnumber_rounded, assignees_split) |> 
  summarize(counts = sum(is_match))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   df_itemnumber_rounded [3]
  df_itemnumber_rounded assignees_split                counts
  <chr>                 <chr>                           <int>
1 df_2002_767           FORENEDE BRYGGERIER                 0
2 df_2002_77            DSM IP ASSETS BV                    0
3 df_2002_77            DSM NV,GIST BROCADES NV             1
4 df_2002_77            INRA INST NAT RECH AGRONOMIQUE      0
5 df_2002_78            DE FORENEDE BRYGGERIER AS           0
```

If you only want to get the ids where there's at least one match, you can do:

```
df1 |> 
  mutate(is_match = str_detect(tolower(assignees_split),
                               paste0(tolower(trimws(df2$citedp_assignee, which = "both")),
                                      collapse = "|"))) |>  
  group_by(df_itemnumber_rounded, assignees_split) |> 
  summarize(counts = sum(is_match)) |> 
  filter(!all(counts == 0))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   df_itemnumber_rounded [1]
  df_itemnumber_rounded assignees_split                counts
  <chr>                 <chr>                           <int>
1 df_2002_77            DSM IP ASSETS BV                    0
2 df_2002_77            DSM NV,GIST BROCADES NV             1
3 df_2002_77            INRA INST NAT RECH AGRONOMIQUE      0
```

---

### Another shot after TO provided some sample data.

So here's the idea:

- Note: I named the two data frames df1 (assignees) and df2 (companies).
- We first do some basic cleaning of the character columns, e.g. convert everything to lowercase characters and get rid of some whitespaces at the beginning/end.
- We then go through each row/assignee in df1 (hence `rowwise`) and count how often this assigne name occurs in df2 for the same company identifier.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df1 |> 
  mutate(assignee_new = tolower(trimws(assignees_split, "both")))

df2 <- df2 |> 
  mutate(citedp_new = tolower(trimws(citedp_assignee, "both")))


df1 |> 
  rowwise() |>  
  mutate(assignee_count = length(str_which(df2$citedp_new[df2$df_itemnumber_rounded == df_itemnumber_rounded],
                                           assignee_new))) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  print(n = 100)
```

which gives (only printing the first 20 rows):

```
# A tibble: 100 x 5
    df_itemnumber_rounded `Publication Number` assignees_split                    assignee_new                   assignee_count
    <chr>                 <chr>                <fct>                              <chr>                                   <int>
  1 df_2012_2175          WO2006046567A1       "KOMATSU MFG CO LTD "              komatsu mfg co ltd                          0
  2 df_2012_2175          WO2006046567A1       " SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD "           suntory holdings ltd                        0
  3 df_2012_2175          WO2006046567A1       " SUNTORY LTD "                    suntory ltd                                 0
  4 df_2012_2175          WO2006046567A1       " FURUKUBO S "                     furukubo s                                  0
  5 df_2012_2175          WO2006046567A1       " IZUMI T "                        izumi t                                     0
  6 df_2012_2175          WO2006046567A1       " KAKUDO Y "                       kakudo y                                    0
  7 df_2012_2175          WO2006046567A1       " TAKAOKA S"                       takaoka s                                   0
  8 df_2002_4897          DE3149931A1          "SUN CHEM CORP "                   sun chem corp                               0
  9 df_2002_4897          DE3149931A1          " SUNTORY LTD"                     suntory ltd                                 0
 10 df_2012_9460          WO2013002007A1       "SUNTORY BEVERAGE & FOOD LTD "     suntory beverage & food ltd                 0
 11 df_2012_9460          WO2013002007A1       " SUNTORY BEVERAGE&FOOD LTD "      suntory beverage&food ltd                   0
 12 df_2012_9460          WO2013002007A1       " SUNTORY FOOD & BEVERAGE CO LTD " suntory food & beverage co ltd              0
 13 df_2012_9460          WO2013002007A1       " SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD"            suntory holdings ltd                        2
 14 df_2016_6247          WO2016114276A1       "SUNTORY BEVERAGE & FOOD LTD "     suntory beverage & food ltd                 0
 15 df_2016_6247          WO2016114276A1       " SUNTORY FOOD & BEVERAGE CO LTD " suntory food & beverage co ltd              0
 16 df_2016_6247          WO2016114276A1       " SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD"            suntory holdings ltd                        3
 17 df_2016_6248          WO2016114277A1       "SUNTORY BEVERAGE & FOOD LTD "     suntory beverage & food ltd                 0
 18 df_2016_6248          WO2016114277A1       " SUNTORY FOOD & BEVERAGE CO LTD " suntory food & beverage co ltd              0
 19 df_2016_6248          WO2016114277A1       " SUNTORY HOLDINGS LTD "           suntory holdings ltd                        3
 20 df_2016_6248          WO2016114277A1       " IBUSUKI D "                      ibusuki d                                   0
```

I tested it by increasing the size of df1 to 10000 rows and df2 to 150000 rows (of course, you real-life pattern might be more complex) and it runs just fine in 20 seconds on my machine:

```
df1_new <- df1 |> 
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 100))

df2_new <- df2 |> 
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 1500))

t1 <- Sys.time()

df1_new |> 
  rowwise() |>  
  mutate(assignee_count = length(str_which(df2_new$citedp_new[df2_new$df_itemnumber_rounded == df_itemnumber_rounded],
                                           assignee_new))) |> 
  ungroup()

Sys.time() - t1

Time difference of 20.36699 secs
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with my small dataframe, where I limit the observations of the two dataframes to 100. But it gives me the following error, when I let it run on the original df:Fehler: Problem with `mutate()` input `is_match`.
x Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL)
i Input `is_match` is `str_detect(...)`.

Comment: Can you please provide a real exsmple of your data through dput? Since your data is too large please provide dput(head(yourdataframe1, 100)) and dput(head(yourdataframe2,100)).

Comment: I have included the data in my example above.

Comment: Did you? I don't see any edits since yesterday.

Comment: Sorry you were faster. I have just copied it in :) Thank you

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks to you I have managed it!! This is great! Thank you very much.